# Unable to connect to a silo in a container from outside the docker network

Tags: c#, docker, orleans

I am trying to set up an **Orleans** silo inside a **Docker** container. The client will not be in a container in the beginning.

I am using *Docker on Windows* in *Linux container* mode. 
I am able to have both the client and the silo running and connecting when the client is also in a container.

The silo is configure like this:

```
var builder = new SiloHostBuilder()
                .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.ClusterId = "DOCKER-SILO";
                    options.ServiceId = "EZ-DOCKER";
                })
                .UseAdoNetClustering(options =>
                {
                    options.Invariant = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
                    options.ConnectionString = "server=XXX;user id=orleans;password='XXX';persistsecurityinfo=True;database=orleans;SslMode=None";
                })
                .Configure<EndpointOptions>(options =>
                {
                    var adressList = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
                    options.AdvertisedIPAddress = adressList.First();
                    options.GatewayPort = 30000);
                    options.SiloPort = 11111);
                })
```

The client is configured like this:

```
client = new ClientBuilder()
                .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.ClusterId = "DOCKER-SILO";
                    options.ServiceId = "EZ-DOCKER";
                })
                .UseStaticClustering(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.13"), 30000))
```

The silo is run like this:

```
PS C:\XXX> docker run -p 30000:30000 --expose 11111 --add-host host.docker.internal:192.168.0.13 ezorleanssilolinux
```

Dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
#COPY --from=publish /app .
COPY ["eZ.Orleans.Silo/publish", "."]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "eZ.Orleans.Silo.dll"]
```

When I use `127.0.0.1` as the static gateway ip in the client, it works. When I use any other IP the docker host has, I get the following error in the silo logs:

```
Gateway received unexpected non-proxied connection from *sgn/01111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/11111111 at source address 172.17.0.1:38428
```

Why am I getting this error when trying on any other address than localhost? `netstat -n -a` shows me that the silo is listening on 0.0.0.0 on the host.

Comment: Is it possible to include some/all of your Dockerfile in the above?

Comment: Im having the same issue, did you figure out what is happening?

Comment: see https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/8268

Answer (score 0):

after a few hours I've managed to make everything works, check out my Silo Code:

```
 return new HostBuilder()
                .UseOrleans(builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .UseDashboard()
                        .UseAdoNetClustering(options =>
                        {
                            options.Invariant = "System.Data.SqlClient";
                            options.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                        })
                        .Configure<EndpointOptions>(options =>
                        {
                            // Port to use for Silo-to-Silo
                            options.SiloPort = 11111;
                            // Port to use for the gateway
                            options.GatewayPort = 30000;
                            // IP Address to advertise in the cluster
                            options.AdvertisedIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetExternalIpAddress());
                            // The socket used for silo-to-silo will bind to this endpoint
                            options.GatewayListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 40000);
                            // The socket used by the gateway will bind to this endpoint
                            options.SiloListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 50000);
                        })
                        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
                        {
                            options.ClusterId = "ClusterId-ForSign";
                            options.ServiceId = "ServiceId-ForSign";
                        })
                        .ConfigureApplicationParts(parts =>
                        {
                            parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(UserService).Assembly).WithReferences();
                            parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(CompanyService).Assembly).WithReferences();
                        });
                })
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
                    services.AddTransient<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
                    services.Configure<ConsoleLifetimeOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        options.SuppressStatusMessages = true;
                    });
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddConsole();
                })
                .RunConsoleAsync();
        }

        private static string GetExternalIpAddress() => new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
```

Comment: `GetExternalIpAddress() => new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");`  except that you want this to be `inside` and resolvable to the orleans clients.   also see https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/8268